# Error using procedure pointer and user defined type (Fortran 2003)

Tags: pointers, types, fortran

I'm having trouble when making a procedure pointer whose argument is a user defined type. Here is an example code

```
    module general
        use, intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env, only: dp => real64
        implicit none
    type parametros
    integer :: N 
    real(dp) :: mu
    end type parametros

    type ptr_wrapper
    procedure(f), nopass, pointer :: func
    end type ptr_wrapper

    abstract interface
    function f(x1,y)
    import
    real(dp), intent(in) :: x1
    type(parametros) :: y
    real(dp) :: f
    end function f
    end interface

abstract interface
function Prod(x,y)
    import
    real(dp),intent(in) :: x
    type (parametros) ,intent(in):: y
    real(dp) :: Prod
end function
end interface
end module general

module integrandos
use, intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env, only: dp => real64
use general
implicit none

contains
function DUMMYS (x,y) result(VD)
real(dp),intent(in) :: x
type(parametros),intent(in) ::y
real(dp) :: VD
VD = y%mu + x
end function DUMMYS

end module integrandos

program main
use, intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env, only: dp => real64
use general
use integrandos

type(parametros) :: y
    y%N = 12
    y%mu = 5.0d0

procedure(Prod),pointer :: DM_ptr
DM_ptr => DUMMYS

end program main
```

This is a test code and I need to make it a pointer because I will use this as an argument for another function. When I copile it with gfortran I get the following error

```
  procedure(Prod),pointer :: DM_ptr
                              1
  Error: Unexpected PROCEDURE statement at (1)
  structure.f03:259:17:

  DM_ptr => DUMMYS
             1
  Error: Function ‘dummys’ requires an argument list at (1)
```

I don't know why this happens because I created the procedure Prod whose arguments are a real type and a user defined type (parametros)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortran has requirements on ordering of statements.  `y%N = 12` and `y%mu = 5.0d0` are executable statements.  The `procedure(Prod),pointer :: DM_ptr` statement cannot appear after an executable statement.